# Open CryEngine console from lua script

Tags: lua, cryengine

Is there a function in the CryEngine Lua API to open the `~` Console?
I cannot find it in the [Lua (`ScriptBind`) API reference](http://docs.cryengine.com/display/CEPROG/ScriptBind+Reference).

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean to open the console by lua script or execute a console command from lua?
As far as that goes, it would be hell of a workaround to run console commands by lua. It would be much easier to expose the c++ function that does the things you want (for example the function which the console command calls) to the lua engine and run it directly (refer to [this](http://docs.cryengine.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=1933355)).

Just in case you want to invoke lua from the console, simply run your script from the console by putting a # in front of it (This only works in Sandbox or when launching with -DEVMODE).